# Vending Machine Project VB: Money Not Displaying As I Would Like

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I'm making a vending machine project in VB and am fairly new to VB. I'm using Visual Studio 2017. Every time I click a button, I want the money to add up in the textbox.

For example, if I click the button 10p  once, and then click it again I would want the textbox to display 20p.

I have tried using += in Visual basic but it doesn't work. I've tried googling solutions but I can't seem to find any, so as always, this is my last resort.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click​
        Dim total_money As Integer​
        Dim clicks As Integer​
        Const pence_sign As String = "p"​
​
        clicks += 1​
​
        txtMoneyDisplay.Text = (10 * clicks) & pence_sign​
```

I have no error messages which I can't fix.

But if I click 10p twice it won't show as 20p it will keep on showing as 10p, no matter how many times I click, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix you should apply is moving this line `Dim clicks As Integer` to be outside of the function `Sub Button1_Click` making it a member variable instead of a local variable.

Example:

```
Public Class Form1
     Dim clicks As Integer
     Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click​
        Dim total_money As Integer​​
        Const pence_sign As String = "p"​
        clicks += 1​
        txtMoneyDisplay.Text = (10 * clicks) & pence_sign
```

**Simple Further explanation**

Local variables will be re-created each time the function is fun. They will be assigned either the default value (in the vase of Integers, this will be 0 (Zero)) or whatever value you initialise them to.

Moving the declaration to be outside of the function turns them in to Member Variables. Member variables hold their value as long as the class containing them (and the Object referencing the class) remains in existence. In this case, the Form class will remain in existence while the form is displayed. The member variable will be reset when the class is re-created (or the Form is re-displayed)

**Additional**
You may want to include a button to return the customer money to them, in code for your app, this would translate to a function that will set the `clicks` member variable to 0. This is the same as re-initialising the member variables, resetting your applications state to the same as when it first loaded.

This is an MSDN article that may help you: [Variable Declaration in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/variables/variable-declaration)

Comment: Thank you! That's solved part of my problem, however, now all the numbers show up next to each other like now I click 10p twice and 20p will show, but next to 10p. How do I make 20p show up by itself and 10p disappear?

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed the error in my code, I mistyped something- silly mistake but thank you for helping me. :-)